# Error becoming root centos

Tags: centos, sshd, ssh-agent

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to become root

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo su -
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
* Error: Problem adding; giving up
```

I have tried `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` and I'm got `Agent pid 14714`

Comment: why sudo su? Why not sudo -s?

Comment: My vague guess would be PAM, have you ever changed your PAM configuration to login with certificates, LDAP, Kerberos…? (CentOS released a `pam` update this week or last week, maybe you're bitten by a bug or new config?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh-agent -k` then the passphrase was entered again and solved problem